# Shouldn't square braces followed by curly braces cause an error for array initialization?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

This question is from the context of using the Spring 3 framework with a GWT front end as generated by the Spring Scaffolding process.

## Question 1

There are two questions I have for the block below. One iis the 'new String[] { key };' part. How is it okay to have the square brackets with curly braces directly after them?
Shouldn't square braces followed by curly braces cause an error for array initialization?

## Question 2

Also, it says that this method returns the Primary Key fields in the order they are required by the DAO layer, but it looks like this method could return a maximum of one key with the Object[] and the keyValuesAsText[]. Since the input is only a String how could that possibly be expanded to return an array of keys for DAO objects?

Since this is my first question on stackoverflow any suggestions would be appreciated as to the quality of the question and the way I asked the question.

### code

```
/**
  * Returns the Primary Key field values in the order they are required by the DAO     
   layer to find by primary key
  * @param key
  * @return
  */
protected Object[] getPrimaryKeysFromGoogleKey(String key) {
    String[] keyValuesAsText = new String[] { key };

    Object[] keyValues = new Object[keyValuesAsText.length];
    keyValues[0] = new Integer(keyValuesAsText[0]);

    return keyValues;
}
```

Comment: Is this a Java or GWT question? Should be tagged as Java rather than GWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

```
String[] keyValuesAsText = new String[] { key };
```

This one of Java's array creation syntaxes.  The other one would be

```
String[] keyValuesAsText = { key };
```

Using this syntax Java infers the type of the array based on the type of the variable that is declared on the same line.

If you write:

```
String[] keyValuesAsText;
keyValuesAsText = {key};
```

This will not work, since Java will not infer the type of the array.  In this case you would have to write:

```
String[] keyValuesAsText;
keyValuesAsText = new String[] {key};
```

I'm not sure if this is a good language design feature or not, since the compiler could infer the type of the array based on the type of the variable.

Question 2:

```
protected Object[] getPrimaryKeysFromGoogleKey(String key) {
    //creates an array with only one value so keyValuesAsText.length is always 1 
    String[] keyValuesAsText = new String[] { key };

    //sames as Object[] keyValues = new Object[1];
    Object[] keyValues = new Object[keyValuesAsText.length];

    //sets the first value of the keyValues array to the Integer.parseInt(key);
    keyValues[0] = new Integer(keyValuesAsText[0]);

    //the entire method could be replaced with the following line:
    //return new Object[] { new Integer(key) };    
    return keyValues;
}
```

It always returns an array of Objects with only one value (the integer parsed from key).

Comment: Thank you Nick!
If that is C#'s array initializer syntax then why does it work in Java?

On the second ansewr, thanks. You confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: It's the same thing.  Sorry I thought you were talking about C#. I usually only post to C# posts.